# SQL Server : select max year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fairly large table of data with multiple years worth of accounts with in it. I'm trying to write a query that will simple pull back the latest year.

However I have tried a number of queries, some from this site that seem to work for other but I can not get it to work on my data set.

The table data looks like so:

[image: Sample Data]

So in this example I need to bring back the 2018 year only. The query that I thought might work was:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Accounts A     
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT [Account No], MAX(Year) AS MaxYear 
     FROM dbo.Accounts
     GROUP BY [Account No]) MaxYear ON A.[Account No] = MaxYear.[Account No] 
                                    AND A.Year = MaxYear.MaxYear
```

However this still provides me three records on the Max part when I look for the example account number above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

PS: The `Year` datatype is `Float` and `Account No` is `nvarchar(255)`

Comment: by `this still provides me three records on the Max part when I look for the example account number above` do you mean 3 records with 2018, 2017, 2016 years, or three records with each row `2018` years?

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Accounts where Year = (Select Max(Year) FROM dbo.Accounts)
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work as I have thousands of historical accounts some ending in 2016, 2017, 2018. This misses a huge amount of the data as it will only join on the max year 2018. I need to find the latest year for each account number.

Comment: @Carlos80 I am not using any Join in the query. Also, all the historical records are in same table, right? and you want to know the account opened in the latest year, right?

Comment: Hi Sonal, that is correct, apologies I know you are not joining bad wording on my part. When I run this against my table of data I get only get rows with the year 2019 and thats all, so not getting any accounts that were last seen in 2016,2017,2018. I don't just want the max year I want the last year each account was seen. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
SELECT A.*
FROM dbo.Accounts A where A.Year= (select max(year) from dbo.Accounts)
```

use top

```
select TOP(1) WITH TIES * from dbo.Accounts
order by Year desc
```

Comment: Yes, both solutions are possible. It depends which is better, so your answer with both solutions is great :)

Comment: But the second one will only return one row which doesn’t sound right

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 with ties * from dbo.Accounts
order by Year desc

Answer (score 1):

Then don't group by the account number in the sub-query?

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Accounts A     
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT MAX(Year) AS MaxYear 
    FROM dbo.Accounts
    ) MaxYear

ON A.Year = MaxYear.MaxYear
```

By grouping by the account number *(and then joining on it)*, you were getting each account's max year, rather than the entire table's max year.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work as I have thousands of historical accounts some ending in 2016, 2017, 2018. This misses a huge amount of the data as it will only join on the max year 2018. I need to find the latest year for each account number.

Comment: @Carlos80, you should clarify that in your question

Comment: @Carlos80 ***THAT*** is exactly what you already had.  The three records in your screen shot are for ***different*** accounts.

Comment: MatBailie, thanks, you are correct THAT is what I already have as an original dataset and so in that example you can see we had a record for this account in 2016, 2017 and 2018. This is the same account and so I'm just trying to pull the latest year which would be one row for the 2018 year.

Comment: @Carlos80 - No...The three rows all have ***different*** account numbers...  You're getting the latest year per account, from three different accounts, which is three different rows...  If they're the same account the problem you have is that there are *(at least)* three ***different*** account numbers for the same account, which is completely FUBAR and ***that*** is what needs to be fixed.

Comment: @carlos80 Hello?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand year is part of the accountNo column meaning only the first part is the real account number and you want max (last) year per account

```
SELECT AccountNo, max_year
FROM Accounts
JOIN (SELECT substring(accountno, 1, 6) as accno, max(year) max_year
      FROM accounts
      group by accno) as max_acc ON max_acc.accno = substring(accountno, 1, 6) AND year = max_year
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Joakim, I was hoping this would work as you have got it spot on. Even though the account number seems different they are the same account just with different year reference. However running your code (and it makes complete sense) it still pulls back all three records instead of just the record with the max year (2018) and this was always my original problem.

Comment: It works when I run it so my sample data must be incorrect, could you add more sample data that illistrates you problem. This is my test,[db-fiddle]( https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef114851c9f075ae9cbb891f106167e9)

Comment: @Carlos80, please check my db-fiddle